# Vertical LM Curve

Tags: macroeconomics

What causes a vertical LM curve?
A vertical LM curve seems counterintuitive to me because plotting the LM curve requires us to examine the effects of a change in Y (output/income). But for vertical LM curves, there are no changes in income. Please help with this.